# R: How to extract dates from a time series

Tags: r, date, time-series, raster

How can I extract dates from a times series?
Here is a time series:

```
x = seq (1, 768)
myts <- ts(x, start=1982, frequency=24)
```

Originally I needed to create a vector holding date/time data for the `rts` function, The observations start 1982 with 2 measurements per month going till 2013.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try:

```
time(myts)
```

or perhaps:

```
library(zoo)
as.yearmon(time(myts))
```

Comment: if frequency = 12 then can use zoo::as.Date. x = seq (1, 768); myts <- ts(x, start=1982, frequency=12); zoo::as.Date(myts)

Answer (score 12):

In case you need `POSIX*` objects -- which is probably not appropriate when working with half-monthly data, but might come in handy when dealing with higher temporal resolutions -- you could also use `date_decimal` from **lubridate**.

```
library(lubridate)
mts <- as.numeric(time(myts))

## 'POSIXct, POSIXt' object
tms <- date_decimal(mts)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function. The input is **a time series** in r. And the output is **a list containing all time** array from the start time to the end time.

With the help of the list, you can use `window()` function to truncate a time series very conveniently.

```
getTStime <- function(ats){
  start <- start(ats)
  end <- end(ats)
  time <- list()
  time[[1]] <- start
  m <- 2
  while(!(identical(start, end))){
    start[2] <- start[2] + 1
    if (start[2]==13){
      start[1] <- start[1] + 1
      start[2] <- 1
    }
    time[[m]] <- start
    m <- m + 1
  }
  return(time)
}
```